# jquery - printelement() on click

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-plugins, printing

I am trying to get a colorbox to print using jquery printElement. The problem is this code does not work. If I do not wrap the on() round it soon as the color box loads the print dialog for the printer opens.

Otherwise it does not print on the click. I get the error in console 
**$("#toprint").printElement is not a function**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.printElement.js"></script>
<link href="css/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#print-invoice").on("click", function(event){
            $('#toprint').printElement();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: _"It does not work"_ is **never** a sufficient problem description.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#print-invoice").click(function(){
            $('#toprint').printElement({printMode: 'popup'});
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not given proper path of your jquery.printelement.js. You have to give full path of your js like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery.printElement.js"></script>
```